# How to get the version of the jQuery jqGrid used in Craig Stunz's demo source code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I download Craig Stunz's demo application from [his blog](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/17/38229/) and want to update it to the latest version of jQuery jqGrid but don't know how to get the current version in the source code. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `grid.base.js` you can see the following...

```
 /*
 * jqGrid  3.5 alfa 2 - jQuery Grid
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * Date: 2009-04-02 rev 89
 */
```

So it looks to be v3.5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that, but I know that in the head section of the page you have jQuery UI script tag with the version (1.8.1 is the latest i think). I suppose that by this version you can judge which version of the jqGrid is included in the UI package.